# ¿Como crear un backend para una app angular?

Tags: angular, backend

Quiero crear un backend service para una nueva app Angular. Sin embargo me contesto ng: `The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found`. Aqui esta mi version de Angular:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming>ng g s backend
The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming> ng v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.7
Node: 12.14.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.7
@schematics/angular          9.0.7
@schematics/update           0.900.7
rxjs                         6.5.3
```

Comment: Simplemente ejecuta este comando desde la carpeta raíz de tu proyecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes estar dentro del proyecto para poder ejecutar el comando de generar el service navega con "cd" hasta la raiz del proyecto y ejecuta de nuevo el comando.

Comment: Asi es lo que intenté `C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\plAtform\plAtform>ng g s backend`. Obtengo :
`The generate command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.` Es lo mismo para `C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\plAtform\plAtform\plAtform>ng g s backend`

Comment: intentaste ejecutar el comando dentro de la carpeta app?

Comment: Si, al principio hicé `ng new patients-app` en `C:\Users\antoi\Documents`

Comment: ng new es para crear el proyecto si es asi y usaste ese comando, no estas equivocando de ruta patients-app no esta en las primeras ruta que comentaste arriba, debes situarte en la carpeta app de tu proyecto